# Windows Media Player not offering "Rip CD" option for some CDs

Tags: cd

I've been using Windows Media Player to rip my CDs into .flac files, with no problems seen.

Except, there are six discs, out of nearly 800, for which WMP has the "Rip CD" faded out, with no obvious way of doing the rip:

| Number | Date bought | Where | Title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1986-12-13 |  | Simon And Garfunkel (*Rips fine, even after 35 years*) |
| … | … | … | … |
| 479 | 2004-06-07 | Store-A | RCA Victor - Classical Mob Hits |
| 507 | 2005-06-09 | Store-B | Cabaret |
| 510 | 2005-10-25 | Store-C | Musique Judeo-Baroque |
| 511 | 2005-10-25 | Store-C | A Discovery of Chinese Folk Tunes |
| 512 | 2005-12-01 | Store-D | Pachelbel - Canon in D (With ocean sounds) |
| 521 | 2006-02-?? | Store-E | Ray Stevens - Everything Is Beautiful |

**What would be causing WMP to not offer the option of ripping?**

What makes this situation extra strange is that all of these discs were bought from 5 different stores within a relatively short time span (a less than 2 year period out of the last 35 years).

#### UPDATE:

I found the cause of the problem.
WMP remembers what it has ripped in the past, and then doesn't offer the option of ripping again, *even if the ripped files no longer exist*.

A small-scale work-around:

- Individually check *all* the boxes at the left beside each cut.
- This enables the `Rip CD` button.
- Copy the disk as usual.

But what I really want is a large-scale solution.
**How does one get WMP to forget what it has ripped in the past?**

Answer (score 4):

According to the Wikipedia, that era was the midst of manufacturer's attempts to apply copy protection to CDs. If those disks have that enabled, that would explain it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Disc_and_DVD_copy_protection